# short name for a string/dict/list index

Tags: python, list, dictionary

In python I seem to need to frequently make dicts/lists within dicts/lists within dicts/lists and then access these structures in complex if/elif/else trees. Is there someway that I could make a shorthand way of accessing a certain level of this data structure to make the code more concise.

This is an example line of code now:

```
schema[exp][node]['properties']['date'] = i.partition('(')[2].rpartition(')')[0].strip()
```

which is followed by a whole heap of other lines starting with "schema[exp][node]['properties']['foo']"
What I would like is something like:

```
reference_maker(schema[exp][node]['properties']['date'], schema_props)
schema_props['date'] = i.partition('(')[2].rpartition(')')[0].strip()
```

but I can't even really think where to begin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not worried about it changing:

```
schema_props = schema[exp][node]['properties']
schema_props['date'] = ...
```

But if you want the reference to hang around and auto-update:

```
schema_props = lambda: schema[exp][node]['properties']
schema_props()['date'] = ...

node = node + 1

# this now uses the next node
schema_props()['date'] = ...
```

Or without the lambda:

```
def schema_props():
    return schema[exp][node]['properties']

schema_props()['date'] = ...

node = node + 1

# this now uses the next node
schema_props()['date'] = .
```

Comment: @vorpal: All lambda is doing there is creating a function to return the value

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand but what’s the problem with the following?

```
schema_props = schema[exp][node]['properties']
schema_props['date'] = i.partition('(')[2].rpartition(')')[0].strip()
```

Of course, you have to be careful that `schema_props` always points to a still valid entry in your dict. Ie. once you manually reset `schema[exp][node]['properties']` your `schema_props` reference will not update the original dict anymore.

For more elaborate indirection handling, you could build your own collection types which may then always keep a reference to the base dict. (See also: http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes)

Comment: Sorry, i probably didn't express myself clearly. I am taking complex structured user input and using it to fill up the data structure. As I understand it, your solution will take the current value of dict[foo]...[bar] and apply it to a variable. But then when I assign a bit of the user input to that variable it won't store that input in the original nested data structure.